# xfce: Alt-Ctrl-Left Closes All Open Windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

xfce 4.12
It was a freak mis-type of this combo (Was trying to go back using Alt-Left) but I realized after it was pressed, all windows closed not saving anything... I couldn't find anything online. There is nothing in my 'Keyboard->Application Shortcuts' list. How can I change this to not do this command again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut *Ctrl-Alt-Left* move to the next workspace. *Ctrl-Alt-Right* move to the previous workspace and you can find here all your windows still open.

To change this setting, go to "*Settings - Settings Editor - xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts*". Or just set up only one workspace ...